# Got rare behaviour in SwiftUI with checking boolean in ForEach with Struct elements in Array

Tags: foreach, swiftui

I'm trying to understand why this code is working sometimes as expected but sometimes not. Im showing a List of Boxes that can be selected by a simple tap. When a user tapped a box, a Text changes.

I have a struct and a class:

```
struct SelectionBoxItemStruct: Identifiable
{
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var subtitle: String
    var selected = false
}

class SelectionBoxItemClass: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectionBoxItems = [SelectionBoxItemStruct(title: "XXX", subtitle: "YYY"), SelectionBoxItemStruct(title: "XXX", subtitle: "YYY")]
}
```

In the main View I declared the class like this:

```
@ObservedObject var selectionBoxItemClass = SelectionBoxItemClass()
```

And later in a ForEach I do this:

```
ForEach($selectionBoxItemClass.selectionBoxItems) { $selection in
                        Text(selection.selected ? "True" : "False")
                        Rectangle() // Example of a Box
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width/1.2, height: 100)
                            .onTapGesture(perform: {
                                selection.selected.toggle()
                                print(selection.selected)
                            })
                    }
```

It will print correctly after every tap "true, false, true, ...", but the displayed "TextView" shows only sometimes the right Text and changes, but sometimes only the correct value is printed but the Text doesn't change. In conclusion: every build works different.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). At first glance, I can't tell you.

Comment: Certainly not enough code to reproduce your issue.
As already requested, show a `Minimal Reproducible Example`, 
so we can see the problem in action.
As a guess, you could try replacing 
`@ObservedObject` with `@StateObject`.

Comment: Thank you so much @workingdog, changing it to StateObject did solve the problem!